# Inverse image of compact is compact

Tags: general-topology

Let $f : X\to Y$ be a closed map of topological spaces, such that the inverse image of each point in $Y$ is a compact subset of $X$. Is it true that the pre-image of a compact set $K$ is compact?

The answer is yes but I’m not sure how to show it. I just know that the inverse image of a singleton, say $y,$ is contained in the union of finitely many sets which we can call $U_y$. That’s it. Why is the statement of the question true?

I saw this [Why is the inverse image of a compact set under a special sort of function compact?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427374/why-is-the-inverse-image-of-a-compact-set-under-a-special-sort-of-function-compa)

But it’s too old to revive. Can someone post an easy to follow solution. I’ve just read about the finite intersection property but to understand it I had to come read it here:
http://mathonline.wikidot.com/finite-intersection-property-criterion-for-compactness-in-a

Comment: Why isn't Gregory's proof from what you saw useful? It expands on Brian's answer. I know his proof looks cluttered, but if you can sift through it, looks fine to me. Do you want a proof that is more elaborate, more spaced out (good presentation) and therefore easier to follow? Or do you just want to discuss *some* aspects of that answer in this thread? If that is the case, mention those in the question, otherwise it will look like a duplicate. But +1, I think you've made some effort.

Comment: Thanks for responding Teresa. I think I want a proof that is more elaborate and more spaced out. I now understand his proof of the F.I.P after reading the link from above and it’s not bad at all. Brian’s second assertion is also not clear.

Comment: Then I am writing an answer doing what you say, but it will take me some time.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I already did such a proof below.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you, I was doing something else and was planning to come to this later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $C \subseteq Y$ is compact.

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover for $f^{-1}[C]$ by open sets of $X$, so that

$$f^{-1}[C] \subseteq \bigcup \mathcal{U}$$

For each $y \in C$ we know that $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ is compact by assumption and as $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\subseteq f^{-1}[C]$, this compact set is also covered by $\mathcal{U}$. So for each $y \in C$ we have a finite subset $\mathcal{U}_y$ of $\mathcal{U}$ such that:

$$f^{-1}[\{y\}] \subseteq U_y := \bigcup \mathcal{U}_y \tag{1}$$

Next we define $$O_y = Y\setminus f[X\setminus U_y]\tag{2}$$

and note that $$\forall y \in C: y \in O_y\tag{3}$$

and $$\forall y \in C: f^{-1}[O_y] \subseteq U_y\tag{4}$$

**Proof of (3)**: suppose that $y \notin O_y$. This means by def. $(2)$ that $y \in f[X\setminus U_y]$, so there is some $x \in X\setminus U_y$ with $f(x)=y$. But then this $x \in f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ but $x \notin U_y$, contradicting $(1)$. This shows $(3)$.

**Proof of (4)**: let $x \in f^{-1}[O_y]$ be arbitary. If $x \notin U_y$ we'd have that $f(x) \in f[X\setminus U_y]$ so $f(x) \notin O_y$ contradicting that $x \in f^{-1}[O_y]$. So $x \in U_y$ and the inclusion $(4)$ has been shown.

So $\{O_y: y \in C\}$ is an open cover of $C$ and, as $C$ is compact, there are finitely many $y_1, y_2, \ldots y_n \in C$ such that $C \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{y_i}$

Then (using $(4)$ as well): $$f^{-1}[C] \subseteq f^{-1}[\bigcup_{i=1}^n O_{y_i}] = \bigcup_{i=1}^n f^{-1}[O_{y_i}] \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^n \bigcup \mathcal{U}_{y_i}\tag{5}$$

and $(5)$ shows that $\bigcup_{i=1}^n \mathcal{U}_{y_i}$ is a finite  subcover of $\mathcal{U}$ (as it is a finite union of finite sets), as we had to find. So $f^{-1}[C]$ is compact.

Note that continuity of $f$ is never used, just onto-ness and closedness of $f$ and its compact fibres.

Comment: wow. I was actually able to follow that. So you're saying that continuity isn't necessary?

Comment: @Jama thx, I guess.